# If $V^*$ is finite dimensional, is $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra

$V$ is a vector space, and $V^*$ is its dual space.

I get that if $V$ is isomorphic to $V^{**}$ iff $V$ is finite dimensional. And I get that if $V$ is finite dimensional, $\dim{V}=\dim{V^*}$. But if we just have that $V^*$ is finite dimensional, what do we know about $V$? What would it mean to try to start from $V^*$ and work backwards?

Comment: Given a basis $\beta$ for $V$, you can construct a linearly independent subset of $V^*$ of size $|\beta|$ by let $v^*$ be the functional that maps $v\in \beta$ to $1$ and all other elements of $\beta$ to $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working backwards most likely means a direct proof of the contrapositive.  That works, but there's also a neat direct proof:

By the result that you get ($V$ finite-dimensional implies $V^*$ finite-dimensional), if $V^*$ is finite-dimensional, then $V^{**}$ is as well. Define $\iota:V\to V^{**}$ by $\iota(v)(f)=f(v)$ for $v\in V$, $f\in V^*$.  Then $\iota$ is linear and injective, so $\dim V\leq\dim V^{**}<\infty.$

Answer (score 2):

If $V^*$ is finite dimensional then $V^{**}$ is too.

There is an injection $V \to V^{**}$, where $v \in V$ maps to evaluation at $v$. This is an injection because for non-zero $v$, one can choose $v$ to be in a basis, and then construction a linear functional $V \to k$ that is not zero at $v$ (it is one on $v$ and zero on all the other basis elements). But now $V$ injects into $V^{**}$, which is finite dimensional.

Answer (score 1):

"Work backwards" with an indirect proof. Suppose $V$ is infinite dimensional and show $V^*$ is too.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $V^*$ is finite dimensional vector space over the field $\mathbb{F}$. Then, there exists a basis for $V^*$, call it $\beta = \{f_1, f_2, ..., f_n \}$.

Define, for a vector $x \in V$, a map $\hat{x} : V^* \to \mathbb{F}$ by $$\hat{x}(f) = f(x)$$ $\forall$ $f \in V^*$.

Note that $\hat{x}$ is in $V^{**}$. Convince yourself that the map $x \to \hat{x}$ is an isomorphism from $V$ to $V^{**}$.

Then, consider the dual basis of $\beta$, denoted by $\beta^* = \{ \hat{x}_1, ..., \hat{x}_n\}$ where $$\hat{x}_j(f_i) = \delta_{ij} = f_i(x_j)$$ for all $1 \leq i, j \leq n$.

This implies $\beta$ is itself the dual basis of some basis in $V$, namely $\beta = \alpha^*$, where $\alpha = \{x_1, ..., x_n \}$. So, there is a finite basis of $V$.